# Draw Matlab graphs with frame, ticks, on top of graph lines

Tags: matlab, plot

Consider something like

```
figure
plot(sin(0:0.01:pi))
axis tight
set(gca,'box','on','ticklength',[0.02 0.05])
```

then export the graph to PDF or whatever. The lines of the graph are *on top* of the tick labels and the axes. (Furthermore, the lines of the axes don't meet correctly, but that's another story.)

Is there a way (that can be automated) to have the axes drawn on top?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
set(gca, 'Layer','top')
```

according to the [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e35357):

> Layer
>
> ```
> {bottom} | top
> ```
>
> Draw axis lines below or above graphics objects. Determines whether
>   to draw axis lines and tick marks on
>   top or below axes children objects for
>   any 2-D view (for example, when you
>   are looking along the x-, y-, or
>   z-axis). Use this property to place
>   grid lines and tick marks on top of
>   images.

and to visually see the effect (zoomed in 1200%), I save the figure as a PDF file:

[image]

Default (Layer=bottom):

[image]

with Layer=top:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this existed. I'm no stranger to `get(gca)` but this escaped my notice. Thanks!