# How to place axes objects on top of a figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm now using MATLAB R2012b. I want to draw a grey rectangle together with the axes, and want the rectangle to be behind the axes. I tried

```
uistack(gca,'top');
```

but nothing happens.

In [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15P9E/?solution=1-15P9E) they mentioned that

> However, it is possible to place axes objects on top of UIPANEL
>   objects (which were introduced in MATLAB 7.0 (R14)).

So I think there should be some way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
set(gca, 'Layer', 'top')
```

Ref: [Draw Matlab graphs with frame, ticks, on top of graph lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655256/draw-matlab-graphs-with-frame-ticks-on-top-of-graph-lines)