# Matlab line plot overlaps axis when values are zero

Tags: matlab, plot, line, matlab-figure

I have plotted a figure with multiple lines on it, and I have noticed that the lines for the plot overlap the x-axis when they are zero. Is there a way that I can essentially get the x-axis to plot on the top, rather than the lines?

Here is a MWE that does the same thing (I haven't put my exact code up as my dataset is quite big).

```
xdata=1:1:10;
ydata=[1;0.8;0.6;0.4;0.2;0;0;0;0;0];
line(xdata,ydata)
```

After I plot the lines (multiple per plot in my case), I do various other things with the axes so I get what I need (including adding a secondary set of axes). None of this seems to make any difference as to whether the x-axis is plotted on top of the lines or not.

I did have a search online but couldn't find anything to do with this.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3655256/2647279

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer given by Luis is a nice workaround, but the official way to solve this problem is to use the `layer` property of the axis object, see the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html). To plot the axis on top of the data you do

```
set(gca,'Layer','top')
```

To automatically do this for all your plots, you can put the following line in your `startup.m`:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesLayer','top')
```

This kind of answers you do not make up yourself, I only discovered this trick after asking more or less the same question on comp.soft-sys.matlab [many years ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/IC8XFiMrnPM/2bcnNSPYdacJ). See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3655256/2647279).

Comment: +1 I didn't know about that property. Seems like the way to go. Just a nitpick: this doesn't allow you to control the x- and y-axis behaviour independently

Comment: I have marked this as the answer as it is the official way to do it, although both work. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

After having plotted all your lines, plot a line on the x axis with the same color as the axis:

```
hold on
a = axis; %// gives xmin xmax ymin ymax
cx = get(gca,'Xcolor'); %// color of x axis
plot([a(1) a(2)], [a(3) a(3)], 'color', cx)
```

If the lines also overlap with the y axis and you also want that axis to appear on top, add the following:

```
cy = get(gca,'Ycolor'); %// color of y axis
plot([a(1) a(1)], [a(3) a(4)], 'color', cy)
```

Comment: You missed the fact that the line also overlaps the y-axis by a few pixels in the top-left corner ;). Seems a bit brute-force way to solve the problem ...

Comment: @BasSwinckels Thanks. I've added the y axis part, although the OP only asked for the x axis. And yes, it's a workaround rather than a solution.